# Redirect old pages

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have an old website, which has been transfered to a wordpress install, with a lot of pages being numbered (That tells you the age of the website) and I want to redirect them to the main home page for now to limit 404 errors.

Examples of page names:

```
https://example.com/news3068.html
https://example.com/news2464.html
https://example.com/news537.html
https://example.com/news953.html
https://example.com/news2362.html
```

Now I want to redirect anything /news{number}.html to domain.com

How do I do this with regex, I have SEO Redirection Installed as it's able to do regex redirections as was advised to me, but I have no idea how to do this as I haven't come across regex before.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should try out this site: [WPENGINE.com](https://wpengine.com/support/regex/) to learn more about the regex formatting, or even [Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: This might help: http://www.clogica.com/kb/adding-redirects.htm And also: https://regexr.com/

Comment: So now that you have three or four websites about how to use regex, do you want the regex for your redirection problem, or did you simply want to know **how** to redirect the page?

Comment: You can use the regex: `/news\d+\.html`

Comment: The site is using a plugin called - SEO Redirection Free when you put a plus in it removes it. We can't use the ^/news(.*).html method as there are some article with names after the digits and we want to redirect them manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the end

**^/news[0-9]{3,4}.html**

The Breakdown:-
**^/news**   (starts with /news)
**[0-9]{3,4}**  (Contains the numbers 0-9 for 3 to 4 digits.. Only)
**.html**    (finishes with .html)

Hope this helps people in furture - Its working on a wordpress plugin **SEO Redirection Free** as a **Regex** Redirect

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin Redirection By John Godley. Try to make this settings:

Source url: /news(.*).html
Target: https://example.com/
on group "redirections"

Please make sure that you have regex tick box checked, right to source url!

Comment: ^ /news(.*).html - Catches all pages with the title news,I've tried ^/news(\d{1,4}).html & ^/news\d+\.html but neither redirect.  The site is using a plugin called - SEO Redirection Free